# Understanding CardLayout and panel visibility

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

Consider the following:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new CardLayout());

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    panel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    frame.add(panel1);
    frame.add(panel2);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

No matter what, the frame ends up being 1000x1000. It's my understanding that using the card layout, only one panel will be shown at a time - hence if that panel is the 100x100, the frame should also be 100x100? But this is not the case. Even when the frame is green (i.e. it's panel 2 being displayed), the frame is still 1000x1000.

In fact, even adding the line `panel1.setVisiblity(false);` changes nothing; it *still* affects the frame size, making it 1000x1000!

I'm clearly misunderstanding how the card layout and frame sizing works. Can someone clear up my confusion?

Comment: The point of using the CardLayout is that you don't want the frame size to continually change every time the panel changes. This would be upsetting to the user who lets the frame size to the largest panel automatically, but then they adjust the size of the frame to fit their desktop. Then if you swap panels you lose the custom sizing.

Answer (score 1):

> It's my understanding that using the card layout, only one panel will be shown at a time - hence if that panel is the 100x100, the frame should also be 100x100?

No. A `CardLayout` will take the preferred size of the widest and tallest components within it.

Comment: Even when the largest component is invisible? How do I achieve what I'm trying to do then? That is, switch between several different panels of differing sizes